list of "Image File Execution Options" options in windows registry
I'm looking for a comprehensive list of items which can be added for a process/executable in the "Image File Execution Options" key.
Trolling through my registry, I've found several ...

MitigationOptions
MinimumStackCommitInBytes
AppExecutionAliasRedirect
AppExecutionAliasRedirectPackages
FilterFullPath
CFGOptions
DisableExceptionChainValidation
AuditLevel
DisableUserModeCallbackFilter
UseFilter
Debugger

I know what Debugger and MitigationOptions do, those are pretty well documented.  I also understand the use case for FilterFullPath and UseFilter, there's even a SU question about those.
but ... I have not been able to find any documentation, official or otherwise, which lists the available IFEO options.  I'm not looking for an answer here about what any several of these do, I'm looking for a reference to documentation.
Where can I find such a list ?  Or even a collection of references which covers as many of these as can be known about ?

Please note that questions explicitly looking for "a reference to documentation" are off topic on this site. It isn't a bad question, but this topic has been deemed off topic for SuperUser.
